# Feedback request for this small collection of Russian words

Tags: лексикон

Native English speaker here. I'm building a collection of flashcards to learn Russian (that I will eventually share on Anki) and I'm hoping that someone could take 60 seconds to confirm the accuracy of the Russian words in 
[this spreadsheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bfbMv67njodCbEtnwwH6NHW5cJa0PD3c2KsUSs5zvCE/edit#gid=1547172303)

I added a notes column to provide context for some ambiguous words. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks to whoever filled in 90% of the sheet for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: Please, clarify: do you want to learn those very Russian words and you need to proof-read their English translations, or you need those English words translated correctly into Russian? I'm afraid that both English and Russian words have many meaning each, so choosing just one meaning out of many will be arbitrary without context.

Comment: I highly recommend this book https://www.amazon.de/Russian-English-Bilingual-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0241244455/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my original question. I am a native speaker of English and would like someone to tell me if the Russian words are correct. @YellowSky

Comment: @pizzaholic81 I don't recommend making the flash cards by yourself, you can easily mix things up. Why don't you use something made by native speakers instead? I believe that would be more reliable, just my two cents though

Comment: Look, for some English words it's impossible to say which Russian variant is "most common". Take the word "freeze", when it's you who freeze yourself in winter it's "замерзать/замёрзнуть", when a cop shouts "Freeze!" it's "замирать/замереть", and when you freeze something, e.g. water, it's "замораживать/заморозить". Now tell me, which one of these is "most common"? How can I guess that?

Comment: Agreed with @Yellow Sky. The words choice is arguable, but it's another topic. Here, for example, you have really tough words like *tear*: it can be рвать/разрывать as in *to tear apart*, but it can be слеза as in *a tear(drop)*.

Comment: @YellowSky A cop would probably shout "Стоять!" and not "Замирать!" ;)

Comment: @pizzaholic81  Just some thoughts.
38 Sink раковина, мойка  Kitchen sink
46 Masking tape  малярный скотч 
52 Ladle поварёшка, половник  Kitchen tool
106 Remember помнить 
110 Leave оставлять, покидать, уходить 
116 Lie врать, лгать to tell the truth 
120 monitor дисплей Computer screen экран 
127Under - под  Below ниже 
128 Above вверху над 
130 Right  право правый, правильный  
135 Jack разъём As in internet cable plugged into the jack розетка

Comment: It's best to memorize both aspects of a verb at the same time e.g. стучать/стукнуть, замораживать/заморозить. When leaning English, I used to memorize three forms at once, e.g. write/wrote/written.

Comment: @SergeySlepov - Yours is a contextual translation, a kind of localization, but when the US cops shout "Freeze!" they _mean_ exactly "замри!", that's what I meant.

Comment: BTW, lie can also mean лежать... :) As in I'm lying on the bed.

Comment: @V.V. thanks for the help with some of the translations.

Answer (score 3):

A general reminder - language is not a secret code to be translated word for word. Even programming languages, being simple semantically, compared to natural ones, are never translated word for word. You need to provide context for each translation, apart from the obvious borrowings from English such as "odometer/одометр".

Most of your English words can be translated by multiple Russian ones (same goes for, say, Italian or even German). If you simply want "the most common" then again, is it statistically most common among a general corpus? news? science reports?

If you want your mini-project to produce useful results, add a few sentences using the English words and ask for Russian equivalents one would use in translating those sentences. There is a reason dictionaries exist, and it is exactly this ambiguity of translation. Even the all-knowing(not!) Google Translate gives you several variants: [image: GoogleT example screenshot]

PS I fixed a couple of words and provided some comments, but as it stands now, the table is not even "most common translation according to an average person", especially verbs. If you're up for some dry reading, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfective_aspect) is one of huge reasons. In Russian verbs aspect is encoded into the word, not indicated by a tense like in English (eg do/did/have done etc can all be translated by several verbs with a different prefix, plus the usual grammatical ending)

Comment: Thanks for the help and yes, as an English speaker I spent my whole life being completely unaware of the imperfect tense (and subjunctive for that matter) until I learned Spanish. You're right about how it would have been better to use an English sentence as an example